# I have trouble setting up a cron job in Plesk after reading documentation. How do I do this right?

Tags: plesk, cron

I have a WordPress plugin which doesn't work with WordPress' cron. I don't know why, it just doesn't, so I had to move the cron job to server side.

At the moment I'm using

```
php --no-check-certificate https://example.com/path/to/file.php
```

The full code is:

```
*/10    *   *   *   *   php --no-check-certificate https://example.com/path/to/file.php
```

I read that I had to add --no-check-certificate considering it's https.

I tried simply`wget https://example.com/path/to/file.php`, but didn't work. Any idea how I can make it work?

Comment: I think you should contact to plugin developer.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the cronjob supposed to access a web location via HTTP in order to make it execute instead of not directly executing it with the PHP executable?

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
*/10 * * * * wget -O /dev/null --no-check-certificate https://example.com/path/file.php
```

Also, `--no-check-certificate` is a switch of `wget`, not `php`.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question directly due to my lack of knowledge about cron jobs. What I do know is that the cron job should execute the php file the same way I would execute it manually in the browser by copy pasting the direct link. I added your command to see if it works. Hope it does. Thanks.

Comment: The cronjob I suggest is just accessing the webpage as you were visiting it through a web browser. That will cause web server to run the PHP script for you. I believe my answer is correct since your example had `--no-check-certificate` that is a switch for `wget`. The cronjob is just running this command and saving output to `/dev/null`. If you'd rather use the output as a log, you can change this location to a real file.